# Textbox control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i have a problem whith my small project asp.net.

I have a variable :

```
String pr_name;
```

and a textbox control.

I get data form textbox and set to variable:

```
String pr_name = Textbox1.Text;
```

but i received value :

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox

or null.
```

WHY ?

Comment: You get the value where? Where are you seeing that value. This is not typical behavior.

Comment: Is this on a postback during Init() or PreInit() or OnLoad() or what part of the lifecycle?

Comment: thank all.ispostback is problem